# unordered_map::find() and two iterators

Tags: class, c++11, iterator, return-value, unordered-map

Having a class with a private member

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, size_t> myMap;
```

and the corresponding getter

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, size_t> getMyMap() const {return myMap;}
```

I observe strange behaviour by applying std::unordered_map::find() two times, each time saving the returned iterator, e.g.

```
auto pos1 = test.getMyMap().find("a");
auto pos2 = test.getMyMap().find("a");
```

Altough I look for the same key "a" the iterator points to different elements. The following sample code illustrates the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class MyMap{
 public:
  MyMap(){
    myMap= {
      {"a", 1},
      {"b", 2}
    };
  }

  std::unordered_map<std::string, size_t> getMyMap() const {return myMap;}

private:
  std::unordered_map<std::string, size_t> myMap;
};

int main(){

  MyMap test;

  auto pos1 = test.getMyMap().find("a");
  auto pos2 = test.getMyMap().find("a");
  std::cout << pos1->first << "\t" << pos1->second << std::endl;
  std::cout << pos2->first << "\t" << pos2->second << std::endl;
}
```

Compiling with g++ -std=c++11 and running gives

```
b   2
a   1
```

where the first line is unexpected. It should be "a 1".

Changing the code to

```
  auto pos3 = test.getMyMap().find("a");
  std::cout << pos3->first << "\t" << pos3->second << std::endl;
  auto pos4 = test.getMyMap().find("a");
  std::cout << pos4->first << "\t" << pos4->second << std::endl;
```

results in the correct output

```
a   1
a   1
```

Furthermore just creating an unordered_map in the main file and applying find() works. It seems the problem is connected to the getter-method, maybe to return-value-optimisation. Do you have any explanations for this phenomena?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code. The `getMyMap` returns a *copy* of the map, a copy that is destructed once the expression `test.getMyMap().find("a")` is done.

This means you have two iterators that are pointing to no longer existing maps.

The solution is very simple: Make `getMyMap` return a constant reference instead:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, size_t> const& getMyMap() const;
```

---

That it seems to work in the latter case, is because that's a pitfall of undefined behavior, it might sometime *seem* like it works, when in reality it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

`test.getMyMap().find("a");`  does `find` on a copy of original `myMap` which is destructed after the expression is complete, making the iterators `pos1` and `pos2` to non-existing map, invoking an *undefined behaviour*

Instead you can *play* around like following :

```
  auto mymap = test.getMyMap() ;   // Store a copy

  auto pos1 = mymap.find("a");    // Then do stuff on copy
  auto pos2 = mymap.find("a");
```

Comment: I feel a little bit dumb... The answer of @JoachimPileborg gives the perfect solution in my case. Many thanks to both of you!